# Why do old/new style python classes differ in how slices are passed to __getitem__

Tags: python, python-2.7

Debugging some stuff I noticed this difference:

```
class A:
  def __getitem__(self, x):
    print x

class B(object):
  def __getitem__(self, x):
    print x

a = A()

b = B()
```

Then

```
>>> a[2:]
slice(2, 9223372036854775807, None)
>>> b[2:]
slice(2, None, None)

>>> a[:2]
slice(0, 2, None)
>>> b[:2]
slice(None, 2, None)
```

I have basically gathered that the old style classes will supply numbers (0/INT_MAX) for the start and stop arguments of slice, (though step is an interesting exception).

But I am curious, why? What sort of implementation detail would cause that.

Comment: Old-style classes have a lot of weird quirks.

Comment: Another *great reason* to use Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation detail you're looking for is that the `type` of old-style instances - not the old-style class, but the type - implements [`__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__). `__getslice__` is the old way to implement slicing, and when `__getslice__` is used, non-provided left and right slice endpoints are converted to 0 and `sys.maxsize` respectively before `__getslice__` is invoked.

The type's `__getslice__` then looks for a `__getslice__` method in the class, doesn't find one, and uses your `__getitem__` method, constructing and passing it a slice, but the `sys.maxsize` conversion has already happened.

You can see the `__getslice__` implementation in [`Objects/classobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#L1177) as `instance_slice`. Note that the C function takes two `Py_ssize_t` integers as slice endpoints, and doesn't have any concept of a non-provided endpoint.

Comment: Can you expand on what the distinction between the class and the instance's `type` is?